# ¿Qué error cometo al implementar esta estrategia?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Intento desarrollar el siguiente script, para el cálculo del MACD.

```
# Importación de datos
import pandas
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

ticker = "GOOG"
start = "2020-01-1"
end = "2021-4-23"
nom_val = "GOOG"
df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
df.rename(columns={'High': 'high',  'Low': 'low', 'Open':'open', 
                      'Close':nom_val, 'Volume':'volume', 'Adj Close':'adj close'}, inplace=True)
df_valor = df[[nom_val]]

# Cálculo del MACD y de la señal.

valor_macd = df_valor.copy(deep=True)

def get_macd(valor_macd, fast, slow, smooth):
    valor_macd["exp1"] = df_valor[nom_val].ewm(span = fast, adjust = False).mean()
    valor_macd["exp2"] = df_valor[nom_val].ewm(span = slow, adjust = False).mean()
    valor_macd["macd"] = valor_macd["exp1"] - valor_macd["exp2"]
    valor_macd["signal"] = valor_macd["macd"].ewm(span = smooth, adjust = False).mean()
    valor_macd["buy"] = 0
    valor_macd["sell"] = 0
    return valor_macd

valor_macd = get_macd(valor_macd, 26, 12, 9)
```

Implemento una estrategia.

```
def implement_macd_strategy(valor_macd):           
    if valor_macd.iloc[i, 3] > valor_macd.iloc[1, 4] :     
            valor_macd.iloc[i, 5] = 1
    else:
        if valor_macd.iloc[i, 3] < valor_macd.iloc[1, 4]:
                valor_macd.iloc[i, 6] = -1
    return valor_macd
valor_macd = implement_macd_strategy(valor_macd)            
valor_macd
```

Me devuelve:

[image: retorno de la estrategia]

Si estuviera bien implementada esta estrategia, si el valor en la columna **macd** del df **valor_macd** es > que el de la columna **signal**, deberiamos ver un 1 en la columna **buy**. En caso contrario deberiamos ver un -1 en la columna **sell**.
Si nos fijamos en el la tabla devuelta, esto no es así, luego algo tengo mal implementado en la última parte del script. ¿Cuál es mi error?

Comment: Por que no usas el método apply?

Comment: @Christian. Apply aplica una función a lo largo de un eje del DataFrame. No acabo de ver su aplicación en este script. ¿Por qué me introduce -1 en la columna sell de la primera fila, si macd y signal son o?.

Comment: Supongo que debes.colocar un `if` en caso los valores sean igual, claramente en el primer se está entrando en el bloque `else` pero en teoría no debe de cumplirse la condición ya que `0<0` es `False`

Comment: No llego a ver dónde está la inconsistencia que mencionas, lo que veo es que los valores  de buy y sell respetan el enunciado de tu pregunta ¿exactamente que fila es la que no se corresponde con lo que esperas?

Comment: La fila 0, ¿por qué mete en ella un -1

Comment: Según tu criterio `si macd > signal entonces buy = 1 sino sell = -1` y como 0 no es mayor a 0 sale por  el else.

Comment: En realidad entiendo que a la fila 0 no deberías aplicarle ningún criterio, por que no tienes un `macd` todavía. Yo hasta diría que la primer fila la deberías eliminar.

Comment: @Patricio Moracho
 Una solución pasa por eliminar la primera fila, como bien indicas, ya que no tiene valor macd. No obstante, sigo dándole vueltas al por qué introduce el -1

Answer (score 0):

El código de la segunda semtemcia, no era correcto. Así funciona correctamente:

```
# Importación de datos
import pandas
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

ticker = "GOOG"
start = "2020-01-1"
end = "2021-4-23"
nom_val = "GOOG"
df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
df.rename(columns={'High': 'high',  'Low': 'low', 'Open':'open', 
                      'Close':nom_val, 'Volume':'volume', 'Adj Close':'adj close'}, inplace=True)
df_valor = df[[nom_val]]

# Cálculo del MACD y de la señal.

valor_macd = df_valor.copy(deep=True)

def get_macd(valor_macd, fast, slow, smooth):
    valor_macd["exp1"] = df_valor[nom_val].ewm(span = fast, adjust = False).mean()
    valor_macd["exp2"] = df_valor[nom_val].ewm(span = slow, adjust = False).mean()
    valor_macd["macd"] = valor_macd["exp1"] - valor_macd["exp2"]
    valor_macd["signal"] = valor_macd["macd"].ewm(span = smooth, adjust = False).mean()
    valor_macd["buy"] = 0
    valor_macd["sell"] = 0
    return valor_macd

valor_macd = get_macd(valor_macd, 26, 12, 9)

def implement_macd_strategy(valor_macd):
    for i in range (0, valor_macd.shape[0]):    
        if valor_macd.iloc[i, 3] > valor_macd.iloc[i, 4] :     
                valor_macd.iloc[i, 5] = 1
        else:
            if valor_macd.iloc[i, 3] < valor_macd.iloc[i, 4]:
                    valor_macd.iloc[i, 6] = -1
    return valor_macd
valor_macd = implement_macd_strategy(valor_macd)            
valor_macd
```

Nos devuelve.

[image: Salida del script]